# Read sending data of Android App with Fiddler

Tags: android, proxy, fiddler, decompiling, sniffing

i have an Android App, where i would like to see, how it communicates with the servers (Its an App from the Playstore).

For that i tried to read it out through Fiddler (installed on PC) and the setup worked perfect. The only problem is, that if the App is going through the PC proxy (to be able for Fidler to read the data) its not connecting to the servers. Other Apps or browsers are working.

Tried it with a real smartphone and a android emulator, same result. My questions are right now, if there is a kinda Fiddler app directly for the smartphone (so i dont have to use the proxy) or is the only way to decompile the apk (if possible).

Btw.: I changed the wifi settings for proxy, would maybe help here a extra proxy app aswell?

Answer (score -1):

Your problem ("if the App is going through the PC proxy (to be able for Fidler to read the data) its not connecting to the servers") does not really make sense.

In order to monitor traffic you start fiddler on your PC and get the IP address of your PC in the WiFi. Then you set this IP and the port 8888 as your proxy on your android device. That way you see all traffic from the device in Fiddler. Note you need to configure Fiddler to accept connections from remote computers: "Tools" -> "Options" -> "Connections" -> "Allow remote computers to connect".

Comment: But it is, i've set up everything and tried with different apps, for example the browser and other apps worked fine, only the one app couldn't build up the connection the the server. Could it be that the developers coded some security check, because they didn't want that case?

Comment: Yes it's quite possible the developer has prevented this. Fiddler terminates the SSL connection and provides a different certificate. If the developer checks this and only accepts their own certificate you have no chance to view the traffic.